# SoundCloud API using Soundmanager2 for streaming - reporting

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

I m currently using SC.stream (soundmanager2) on my own player to deliver track from my Website.

My question regards the Reporting. Is Soundcloud API

i m wondering what type of information soundcloud delivers in terms of music listening, number of plays. Abandoned sessions. Full listening  and so on. Based on my account.

Best Regards
Xavier

Comment: Hello All, Anybody has any clue on it. I m still looking forward those informations in order to retrieve a full listening reporting. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering about what metadata you can get from the SoundCloud API, the answer is quite a bit. The SC.Stream only does what is neccesary to get the underlying SoundManager2 instance to play, but if you GET track information specifically, you can get a ton of information.

See the [API documentation here.](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)